# I can't delete an Event Feed with Google data API

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, gdata-api, zend-gdata

Hi Guys I'm trying to delete multiple events from the Google Calendar API (From a date range). I get the feed correctly, this is not the problem. The probleme is the delete function. I get this error : "Error: You must specify an URI to which to post."

Can somebody please help me!

Thank You

```
  $service = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);

  $query = $service->newEventQuery();

  $query->setUser('XXXXX');
  $query->setVisibility('private-XXXX');
  $query->setProjection('full');
  $query->setOrderby('starttime');
  $query->setStartMin('2010-01-20');
  $query->setStartMax('2010-01-28');
  // Retrieve the event list from the calendar server

  try {

      $eventFeed = $service->getCalendarEventFeed($query);

  } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {

      echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();

  }



  // Iterate through the list of events, deleting them //

  foreach ($eventFeed as $event) {

    try{
    $event->delete();
    }
    catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {

        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();

    } 

  }
```

Comment: Nothing to do with App Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using *MagicCookie* authentication, which will give you read-only access. To get read/write access you will need to use *ClientAuth* or *AuthSub* authentication.

**Edit**: For example, here's how to use *ClientAuth*:

```
$user = 'me@example.com';
$pass = 'password';

$service = Zend_Gdata_Calendar::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$client  = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service);
$service = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);

$query = $service->newEventQuery();
$query->setUser('default');
$query->setVisibility('private');
// Rest of your code.
```